# Configure an S3 bucket to be *mostly* public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using S3 to store and serve many files. I'm being a bit vague here deliberately. Just assume it's a lot of files.

There are CDNs in front of it. Currently, the bucket has a policy that makes all files within it publicly readable. This has worked out okay so far.

However, now, I will sometimes want to make a few of those files inaccessible, temporarily, while a moderation team examines them for inappropriate content. We want to be absolutely sure we are not serving inappropriate content.

Do I have any other options other than making the bucket's policy default private, and setting every single one of the public files to be public? I know how to do that (easy to script with the aws cli or other APIs), but it just seems inefficient.

Is there a way to write an S3 security policy which is like "generally everything in here is public, except these files" and have it be efficient?

Does it become inefficient to have "mixed" public/private policies at larger scale?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not (that I've found anyway). A bucket who's policy is set to public overrides the private ACL setting of files within it (why, I have no idea..seems silly if you ask me). In order to have private files on S3 that are truly private, your bucket's policy needs to be set to private, and your public files individually set to be public.

Your alternative might be to utilise 2 buckets, and put your content-in-need-of-moderation in the second bucket instead, marked private. And then, once your moderation team has accepted the content, your software moves the file to the public bucket, removing it from the private one.

Comment: *"why, I have no idea..seems silly if you ask me"*  It's pretty straightforward. Since everything is denied by default, "private" is simply the absence of any read privilege.  With a bucket-wide policy allowing read access, there is no longer an absence of any read privilege.  Private is simply the default state, not explicit deny.  If objects are all individually set to public, there is no need to also make the bucket public.

Comment: ...and thinking about my own infrastructure, I almost never make a bucket public, even when its contents are public.  I always leave this to happen at the object level, leaving the application responsible for setting this when creating objects, and using policies to block the creation of public objects in buckets that should never contain them.

Comment: Thanks. I can't yet upvote here, so this is all I have :)

Comment: @Michael my point with that statement was more about why, in a public bucket, does a single object's private acl setting get overridden by the bucket's policy. There's many use cases for this to be useful, including OP's. Effectively a public bucket policy renders all other read acl's useless, and S3 gives no indication that what you're trying to do won't work.

Comment: *"why, in a public bucket, does a single object's private acl setting get overridden by the bucket's policy"* is for the reason I indicated.  A bucket policy that makes objects public is a grant from the bucket owner that allows any user to read the objects in spite of the fact that they may have a "private" object ACL.  If a public bucket required objects to also be public, then a "public bucket" would be a meaningless concept, because in S3 an object with `x-amz-acl: public-read` is publicly readable, a long as not explicitly denied by policy, even in the complete absence of a bucket policy.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to explicitly deny access to certain objects with [Object Tagging and Access Control Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-tagging.html#tagging-and-policies).

For example, with the following bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyReadIfPrivate",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/security": "private"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Since `Deny` > `Allow`, every object tagged with Key `security` and Value `private` won't be publicly available.